# setter needs to update the object and return something JAVA

Tags: java, setter

```
setPriority(priority: int): ToDoItem
```

setWhat(what: String): ToDoItem

setWhen(when: String): ToDoItem

Each of the three setters returns the updated object. This is a bit different than the normal void versions of the past.

this is an Array List

this is what my UML says.

I am completely lost, I am not sure how to even start at making a setter return an updated version of something, I have an idea its a for loop but im so lost its unreal, any help to push me in the right direction is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your UML appears to be based on a [*fluent interface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), you would typically `return this;` like

```
public ToDoItem setPriority(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
    return this;
}
```

The idea being that a caller may then chain method invocations.

```
ToDoItem a = new ToDoItem().setPriority(10).setWhat("what").setWhen("right now");
```

Comment: There are 3 classes. A main, WeeklyToDoList, and ToDoList.  The ToDoList class is basic class with 2 constructors and the setters and getters, but my professor is specifying that the setters are to return an updated version of the object, would your way of doing it update my object and return the new version?

Comment: That is exactly what it does. The first line of code updates the object, and the second line returns that object ("this"), with the updates done.

Comment: @MLeuck3 There isn't a "new version", the instance isn't changing - but yes, the value is updated and the same instance which contains that value is returned. That is why a setter (or *mutator*) normally doesn't return anything (it isn't creating anything).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, you are talking about fluent api:

```
class ToDoItem{
    private int priority;
    private String what;
    private String when;

    public ToDoItem setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
        return this;
    }

    public ToDoItem setWhen(String when) {
        this.when = when;
        return this;
    }
    public ToDoItem setWhat(String what) {
        this.what = what;
        return this;
    }
}
```